# index exceeds matrix dimensions error with the size function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the following very simple code.

```
>> z=ones(4,4)

z =

     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1

>> size(z)
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

Does anyone know why? Any comment is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A likely cause is: You have a variable called `size`, and that variable is empty. Try `clear size` and then `size(z)`.